# no consigo los fonts adecuado o el setting css adecuado, para el alineado de texto entre caracteres arábigos y estándar

Tags: html, css, fuentes, google-fonts

Como verán en las imagenes, el sistema detecta que estos dos `string` tienen 4 caracteres `UTF-8`, es una vista `html`, ósea que es accesible desde el navegador:

```
//1234
//عباس
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero al colocarlos uno debajo del otro no se alinean, en el texto con caracteres arábigo hay una perdida de espacio pixeles el cual atribuyo al fonts.

implemento `normalize` version `8.0.1` para el reset del css.

he intentado utilizar estos fonts: `consola`, `monospace` y `jetbrain mono` sin ningún resultado positivo.

he investigado que font puede mostrar esto correctamente alineado y me encuentro que al entrar a la consola del navegador se ve de la siguiente forma, casi perfectamente alineado pero con un incremento mínimo de pixeles:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente investigar que Font y setting usa `devtools` de `google chrome browser` pero no encontré absolutamente nada en la documentación, solo necesito como aplican el font del visor de código html y que font usan.

Intente validar como se ve en mi IDE uso PHPStorm y adivinen como se ve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

perfectamente alineados; valido el font y `setting` de mi IDE y son estos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Implemento los mismo en mi HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Code">
            <style>
                body, span {
                    font-family: "Fira Code", monospace !important;
                    line-height: 1.2;
                    font-size: 12px;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
```

y en el sitio web se sigue visualizando mal:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***No encuentro que estoy haciendo mal?***

Esto es lo que sale en el visor de CSS de google chrome:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Update***

y esto es lo que sucede cuando tienes datos en diferentes idiomas:
vista en el sitio web

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haciendo pruebas he visto que la fuente **Courier** consigue un resultado si no exacto, al menos bastante cercano a lo que necesitas.

```css
p {
  font-family: Courier;
}
```

```html
<p>ABCW</p>
<p>كرام</p>
<p>....</p>
```

Comment: ok Listo pero cual es la diferencia que provoca esto??? no se si este asociado a joint que hace el renderizado html entre caracteres arabigos... es posible evitarlo?

Comment: No es posible evitarlo, si te fijas, lo que hace tu IDE para que los caracteres arábicos tengan el mismo tamaño es jugar con la separación entre letras. Habrá combinaciones de letras en las que se vea más el cartón y otras en las que el truco de más el pego.

Comment: es posible en css forzar la separacion de caracteres por hay vi que esto en ingles se le llaman ligaturas...

Comment: Con la propiedad `letter-spacing` podrías jugar con ello, pero ya estarías rompiendo la adaptación que la fuente *Courier* hace para que cada caracter ocupe el mismo ancho.

Comment: eso seria para aplicarlo a las otras fuentes

Comment: no con esa propiedad no funciona.